# In Laravel, how can I access data from a pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel

Maybe I'm implementing wrong. Maybe I'm doing things I'm not supposed to do, but conceptually I think I'm okay.

I have two models, one is `Users`, other is `Communities`, and since it is a many to many relationship I need an intermediate table, Laravel calls them a pivot table. According to Laravel recommendations it is named `communities_users`

Normally, the pivot tables only contain the id's to the main tables. But I need a bit more data. Check this image, the migrations are done to match this diagram:

[image]

Here I have a `role` in the pivot table. Lets say a user belongs to two communities, one as community's president, other as a member.

Of course the `president` will have more capabilities than the `member`, for example, he can accept a `pending` person to become a `member` person, or he can promote a member to a `deputy` status or so...

Now lets say I want to get the names of the people with `deputy` role on a given community. I can easily do that using the Query Builder, by joining the three tables and applying `where('communities_users.role', 'deputy')`,

Now, what if I want to use the ORM and get the whole `User` model?

I'd like to have a function on the Community so it gives me the `users` of a given `role`, maybe:

```
public function users($role) {
    ...
}
```

So I can do things like:

```
$community = Community::find($id);
foreach ($community->users('deputy') as user) {
    ...
    echo user->name; // or whatever
    ...
}
```

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding under the [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) section of the Eloquent relationship docs:

> #### Filtering Relationships Via Intermediate Table Columns
>
> You can also filter the results returned by `belongsToMany` using the `wherePivot` and `wherePivotIn` methods when defining the relationship:

```php
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->wherePivot('approved', 1);

return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->wherePivotIn('priority', [1, 2]);
```

Assuming your Communities model already has a `belongsToMany` relationship set up for Users, you should be able to do something like:

```php
$deputies = $community->users()
    ->wherePivot('role', 'deputy') // or equivalent value
    ->get();
```

Comment: hiden... literally. Thanks a lot. The weherePivot is exactly what I need

Comment: Should we define pivot table on both  `User` and `Community` models ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed No, you don't have to. You can add it to whichever model you want to perform the query through. For example, if you never want get a user's communities, you don't need to add `belongsToMany()` to `User`. If you want to fetch the relationship both ways, you can add it to both. Up to you!

Answer (score 3):

As you said only the model keys will be present on the pivot table:

> By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object.
>   If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them
>   when defining the relationship:
>
> ```
> return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
> ```

So, in order to use additional fields when querying related records you need to tell Laravel that you are storing more columns in your intermediate/pivot table:

```
// Community.php

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
                ->withPivot('role'); // <---
}
```

Now you can get your desired output:

```
$community = Community::find($id);
$deputies = $community->users()->wherePivot('role', '=', 'deputy')->get();

foreach ($deputies as $deputy)
{
    echo $deputy->name;
}
```

Read [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) of the documentation.

---

## Observation

You said:

> ... according to Laravel recommendations it is named `communities_users` ...

At first, I though that this was ok since your models appear to have names in plural (I'm talking about model name, not table name). but then, in your desired output you used `Community` to refer to a model. So I'm gonna quote this from the [Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) section of the documentation:

> #### Many To Many
>
> To define this relationship, three database tables are needed:
>   `users`, `roles`, and `role_user`. The  `role_user` table is derived
>   from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and contains
>   the `user_id` and `role_id` columns.

As you see, the general convention is to name the intermediate table in alphabetic order from the related model but in **singular**, so in your case: `community_user`.

This is the convention that Laravel uses, of couse you can just override the name in the relationship definition passing the intermadiate table name as an additional argument.

Comment: I can always use the explicit name, which is what I mostly do, in the belongsToMany() there's a parameter for explicitly naming the table you want to use. This thing about plural/singular is somewhat a mess, specially when you use non-english table names.

Comment: Of course @luisfer, you can indeed custom the table names. I've just said to clarify the Laravel default convention. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define relationship between models like this :

you told that you have Users model then in Users:

```
public function communities(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Communities::class, 'communities_users','user_id', 'community_id');
}
```

and In your Communities model :

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Users::class, 'communities_users','community_id','user_id')
     ->withPivot("role");
}
```

Now you can access any role type users in your controllers like this :

```
$community = Community::find($id);
$deputies = $community->users()
->wherePivot('role', 'deputy') // by passing different role
->get();

foreach ($deputies as $deputy)
{
    echo $deputy->name; // print names
}
```

Comment: Great thanks! I had the two relationships, and worked fine, the wherePivot is what does the trick! I'll check