# How I can avoid duplicate records for insert

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.6.29

```
if ( HarmFlag::where('post_id', '=', $postId)->where('harm_id', '=', $harm_id)->get()->isEmpty() ) {
      HarmFlag::create([
          'post_id' => $postId,
          'harm_id' => $harm_id,
          'gif_flag' => $gif_flag
      ]);
  } else {
      $harmFlag = HarmFlag::where('post_id', '=', $postId)->where('harm_id', '=', $harm_id)->first();
          $harmFlag->gif_flag = $gif_flag;
          $harmFlag->save();
     }
```

Now it can be seen there are duplicate records for `harm_id=18604` and `harm_id=18605`, but according to what I have coded, it should not happen.

**Update**

Also changed the code to

```
$harmFlag = HarmFlag::firstOrNew(['post_id' => $postId, 'harm_id' => $harm_id]);
$harmFlag->gif_flag = $gif_flag;
$harmFlag->save();
```

but still getting duplicate entries.

**Interesting fact about this is for every duplicate records, the timestamp is also same. As well there is only a second record for all these situation.**

Migration

```
Schema::create('harm_flags', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('harm_id');
    $table->boolean('gif_flag')->default(0);

    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('post_id')->on('posts');
    $table->foreign('harm_id')->references('harm_id')->on('base_harms');
});
```

**Update 2**

changed to

```
HarmFlag::updateOrCreate(
          ['post_id' => $postId, 'harm_id' => $harm_id],
          [
              'gif_flag' => $gif_flag,
          ]
 );
```

but still getting duplicate records.

Comment: you are just getting ->first() not all multiple

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I am getting few records correct and few duplicates, if you can notice `3260-18604` and `3260-18605` combination.

Comment: Do you want to avoid saving duplicate records in the database?, because as I see, `created_at` value for duplicate entries is same

Comment: `CharmFlag::where('post_id', '=', $postId)->where('charm_id', '=', $charm_id)->first();
` this would return just 1 record

Comment: @RahulMeshram yes, I want to avoid duplicate entries in database for which post_id and charm_id combination is same.

Comment: Then create a migration to alter that table with unique combination, it will be better for you. `$table->unique(array('charm_id', 'post_id'));` like this.

Comment: So, you can `CharmFlag::where('post_id', '=', $postId)->where('charm_id', '=', $charm_id)->count()`, if value is more than 0, you go to the `else` case

Comment: I advice to use `FormRequest` for this case, to prevent future duplications. You can use `unique` rule for valdiation.

Comment: @RahulMeshram I am not trying to retrieve the unique record, I want to avoid duplicate entry to table, as my code seems correct, I would like to know , how this exception can happen.

Comment: Exactly, mate, the snippet, I shared with you, will avoid any further entries to save into the database.

Comment: @Tarasovych `isEmpty()` doing same thing as `count()  == 0`.

Comment: @RahulMeshram in stead of using table can I use model?

Comment: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#indexes) this is most safer way to do this. And at model level you just need to catch that exception. Your call mate, I can recommend you the best way.

Comment: @RahulMeshram that seems good, but can not change migration now, as this sis live now having millions of data.

Comment: @RahulMeshram finally I did what you had suggested, changed table structure using a modification migration, thank you, it means all these functions has no guarantee, the database structure must be exactly what we need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the posted answers worked for me, so based on suggestions on comments

1. Removed all duplicate entries with

`DELETE FROM harm_flags WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(n.id) FROM harm_flags n GROUP BY post_id, harm_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x)`

2. Generated new migration to modify harm_flags table

`Schema::table('harm_flags', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->unique(["post_id", "harm_id"]); });`

if there is any better solution, I would like to learn that.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to check `isEmpty`, you can use `firstOrNew()` or `updateOrCreate()` methods

```
$harmFlag = HarmFlag::firstOrNew(['post_id' => $postId, 'harm_id' => $harm_id]);
$harmFlag->gif_flag = $gif_flag;
$harmFlag->save();
```

or

```
$harmFlag = HarmFlag::updateOrCreate(['post_id' => $postId, 'harm_id' => $harm_id]);
$harmFlag->gif_flag = $gif_flag;
$harmFlag->save();
```

please check the document
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#insert-update-delete

Comment: Thank you for this, but is anything wrong with my code?

Comment: This also not solving my issue, still getting duplicate records.

Comment: I hope if you update your table using migration like this `$table->unique(['post_id', 'charm_id']);` it'll solve your problem

Comment: that may remove wrong record in current stage, that is why I am not changing the migration.

Comment: Adding a unique constraint will not change existing records. It will fail to add the constraint if there are records which does not match that constraint. You really should be having at least one unique identifier per row, perhaps the combination of postID and charmID.

Comment: @Qirel yes combination of postID and charmID is unique, but there are other columns beside `gif_flag` and this two, what I can do is keep the first entry of every duplicate entry and remove the later, but equal important is to avoid new duplicate entries.

Comment: @Sethu firstOrNew will only insert if not exists but updateOrCreate will update if exists and if not exists it will insert, so later is my requirement if I will not get any duplicate.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I already suggested `updateOrCreate` and I'm glad you got the solution :)

Comment: @Sethu yes I know, but just thought to let you know, I have also upvoted your answer as I found it is helpful, just expecting not to get duplicate with updateOrCreated, already removed already existing duplicate data and waiting for new data to be inserted to check if it is working fine as the app is live.

Comment: @Sethu but still getting duplicate, just got 20/25 new records with 4 duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

If there's a **post_id** and **harm_id** exists then set the **gif_flag**.
If no matching model exists, create one.

You can try like this :

```
HarmFlag::updateOrCreate(
    ['post_id' => $postId, 'harm_id' => $harm_id],
    ['gif_flag' => $gif_flag]
);
```

Its also improve your code performance.

Comment: It is doing same thing as my code, so it is not solving my issue, but I would definitely like to know, how it will improve my performance?

Comment: Instead of running multiple queries, you run one and use a variable instead. Though the solution by replacing your current code with the one in Sethu's answer is probably the cleanest and better way of going about it.

Comment: you can try this, it is the best way to update  or create if not exist.

Comment: @Qirel I have updated my code, but still getting duplicate entries!

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: Have you cleared you database after making changes in code?

Comment: @svikramjeet no, I can not clear my database, I am looking into new entries and finding there is new duplicate entries.

Comment: CharmFlag::updateOrCreate(
    ['post_id' => $postId, 'charm_id' => $charm_id],
    ['gif_flag' => $gif_flag]
);

Comment: This should not allow the duplicate entries as clearly this method will update (if record exists) else create new

Comment: @prafullaKumarSahu , I am unable to understand why code not effected the response

Comment: @SurenderSinghRawat it is confusing for me too, people are working on this app and I am keeping my eyes on new entries and it seems nothing is solving the problem.

Comment: @SurenderSinghRawat yes I just tried this command as well as `php artisan cache:clear` but does not seems to be changing the result.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu , actually its a pivot table for this check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718378/in-laravel-how-can-i-access-data-from-a-pivot-table/55720197#55720197

Comment: @SurenderSinghRawat no this is not a pivot table, this a new model, I have given sample data by selecting columns as it was too long.

Comment: please update class and migration also in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192253/discussion-between-surender-singh-rawat-and-prafulla-kumar-sahu).

Comment: There is preference for `firstOrNew`, but after going through the documentation I must say `updateOrCreate` is more preferable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Chances for creating duplicates lies within first condition, `->get()->isEmpty()` this seems not working.

Can you please update your query like this and see.

```
if (HarmFlag::where('post_id', '=', $postId)->where('harm_id', '=', $harm_id)->first()) {

  HarmFlag::create([
      'post_id' => $postId,
      'harm_id' => $harm_id,
      'gif_flag' => $gif_flag
  ]);

} else {

  $harmFlag = HarmFlag::where('post_id', '=', $postId)->where('harm_id', '=', $harm_id)->first();
  $harmFlag->gif_flag = $gif_flag;
  $harmFlag->save();

  // you can also use below for update. this is faster and efficient.
  /* 
   HarmFlag::updateOrCreate(
    ['post_id' => $postId, 'harm_id' => $harm_id],
    ['gif_flag' => $gif_flag]
  );  
  */
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$harmFlag = HarmFlag::where([['post_id',$postId],['harm_id',$harmId]])->first();

if($harmFlag)
    $harmFlag->gifFlag = $gif_flag;
else
{
    $harmFlag = new HarmFlag();
    $harmFlag->post_id = $postId;
    $harmFlag->harm_id = $harm_id;
    $harmFlag->gif_flag = $gif_flag;
}
$harmFlag->save();
```